# Data Grid control not showing ObservableCollection data

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm rather new to WPF and C# in general. I'm playing around with it and encountered a problem which I feel like would be a piece of cake for an expert but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to create a simple DataGrid control (within a TabControl) and bind it to an ObservableCollection object.
I use microsoft's [Data Binding Demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) provided in their data binding overview as a basis for my code.

MainWindow XAML:

```
   <Window x:Class="PetProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PetProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="PetProject" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource 
              Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=Dogs}"   
              x:Key="DogsDataView" />
    </Window.Resources>



    <Grid Margin="8,8,8,8">
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Dogs">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DogsDataView}}">
                </DataGrid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-Behind:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace PetProject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        /// 


        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            CollectionViewSource DogsDataView;

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                DogsDataView = (CollectionViewSource)(this.Resources["DogsDataView"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The App XAML is

```
   <Application x:Class="PetProject.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PetProject"
                 Startup="AppStartup">
                 <!--StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"-->
    </Application>
```

code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace PetProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Dog> dogs = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();

        void AppStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
        {
            LoadData();
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();

        }

        public ObservableCollection<Dog> Dogs
        {
            get { return this.dogs; }
            set { this.dogs = value; }
        }

        private void LoadData() {
            Dog Johnny = new Dog("Johnny",1325);
            Dog Diamond = new Dog("Diamond",1327);
            this.Dogs.Add(Johnny);
            this.Dogs.Add(Diamond);
        }


    }
}
```

Dog is just a class implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (which for now does not do anything):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace PetProject
{
    public class Dog : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;
        private string number;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Dog(string name, int number)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number.ToString("D4");
        }


        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help in understanding why the DataGrid is not populated.
Also, any suggestion on bad coding habits or improvement to the code would be very welcome, as I'm in a very initial learning-by-experience phase.
Thanks!

Comment: remove that DogsDataView = (CollectionViewSource)(this.Resources["DogsDataView"]);

Comment: Hi, can you explain why this is necessary? seems to work without removing it (after correcting the private/public problem I had). I am now aware of the fact that it does nothing right now - this might change in the future.

Comment: because you are setting DogsDataView = DogsDataView ; once you use the named object in the window, once you get the same by using the resource

Comment: I don't understand. I add the resource to the MainWindow xaml. Now I declare it in the code-behind, but if I want it to refer to the same data, don't I need to go through the xaml resource reference?

Comment: your res has a key/name so in MainWindow use it like this.DogsDataView  - do not need to declare variable in MainWindow (perhaps change x:Key to x:Name) - btw no code in the View if you do MVVM !!

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to private fields. You can only bind to public properties. As far as the DataGrid is concerned, `Dog` has no information to display.

```
public class Dog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private string _number;

    public Dog(string name, int number)
    {
        Name = name;
        Number = number.ToString("D4");
    }

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
            }
        }
    }

    public String Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _number)
            {
                _number = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Number));
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm prefixing your private fields with underscores because that's standard practice. It's standard practice because having two identifiers which differ only by case is a recipe for confusion and bugs.

Comment: Thanks. I just need to get used to public/private separation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you to read about MVVM principles then maybe choose a MVVM framework to use with WPF. For instance [MVVM light toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) is a good choice to start and understand MVVM.

For your example, here are just a few remarks about your code:

- I suggest you to group all your 'business' data into a viewModel class (see MVVM practices all around the web) - nothing in the `App` class...
- This ViewModel will implement 'INotifyPropertyChanged' interface
- So the **`Dogs` property** will be located into this ViewModel and will **raise the 'PropertyChanged' event** in its setter (what is not currently the case in your sample)
- There are several MVVM frameworks that would 'bind' automatically your views to your view model, but to understand, the main goal is to set your `Window.DataContext` with the appropriate ViewModel.
- That's why you can restore in App.xaml: `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`
- Then to load your ViewModel, you can do something like that to load your Dogs collection:

  ```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
      public MainWindow()
           {
              InitializeComponent();
              Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
           }

          private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
              // For test: LOAD & SET your DataContext here
              //
              var myDogViewmodel = new DogViewModel();
              myDogViewModel.LoadData();
              this.DataContext = myDogViewmodel;
          }
      }
  ```
- Your ViewModel should look like something like that:

  ```
  public class DogViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      private ObservableCollection<Dog> _dogs;
      public ObservableCollection<Dog> Dogs
      {
          get { return _dogs; }
          set
          {
              _dogs = value;
              PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Dogs"));
          }
      }
      public void LoadData()
      {
          // ....
      }
  }
  ```
- Then your `Dog` class must also implement INotifuPropertyChanged interface:

  ```
      public class Dog : INotifyPropertyChanged
      {
          public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

          private string _name;
          private int _number;     

          public string Name
          {
              get => _name;
              set
              {
                   if (_name != value)
                   { 
                      _name = value;
                      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
                   }
              }
          }

          public int Number
          {
              get => _number;
              set
              {
                  if (_number != value)
                  {
                      _number = value;
                      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Number"));
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  ```
- Finally,in your MainWindow.xaml:

>

```
<Window x:Class="PetProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PetProject"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="PetProject" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid Margin="8,8,8,8">
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Dogs">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dogs}" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

It should work now ;) Tell me if it's clear. Get familiar with MVVM...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll definitely get familiar with the MVVM design principle. looks very promising for what I intend to do.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Number"));
and
this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

Comment: There’s no need for MVVMLight here. Much better for OP to set up the DataContext in the usual way.

Comment: If you call PropertyChanged(...) directly, you must be sure that it's not "NULL", else you will get an exception. Syntax with "?.Invoke()" means that if PropertyChanged is null (nobody's listening to this event), it will not invoke (throw / execute) the event, so it's safer (check this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/)

Comment: I would appreciate it very much if you could tell me when it is more appropriate to use MVVM in your opinion and when it is not needed. This (very) initial piece of code will hopefully become a moderately sized GUI, with some not completely trivial interaction logic behind it.

Comment: MVVM patterns help you to structurate your code. If it's a 'small' project like your sample, there is no need to use a MVVM framework. But in larger projects it can be helpfull for many reasons. Base mechanisms are already implemented / Tested. Will look like many other projects. People can come then understand quickly the code, you can test it easily. Faster to implement... If you are skilled enough, maybe in this case, you can implement your own MVVMs patterns. It's what I think, but read more docs !